# Setting Cookie in http response header from AWS lambda Node JS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a Lambda proxy integration enabled, and setting the response headers as part of Lambda output and API Gateway that will return them as part of the HTTP response to the client.

Sample code:

```
callback(null, {
    "statusCode": 302,
    "Location" : "https://somewebsite.com"
    "headers": { "headerName": "headerValue", ... },
    "body": "..."
});
```

I need to send out 3 cookies in the headers. I tried. But, failed:

```
callback(null, {
    "statusCode": 302,
    "Location" : "https://somewebsite.com"
    "headers": { "Set-Cookie": [cookie1String, cookie2String, cookie3String] },
    "body": "..."
});
```

[Edit]
I concatenated the cookie and passed in as the response, the client gets the cookie. But when the client calls the target in "location", the request does not have the cookie in the header.

```
callback(null, {
    "statusCode": 302,
    "Location" : "https://somewebsite.com"
    "headers": { "Set-Cookie": c1=cookie1String;c2=cookie2String; c3=cookie3String] },
    "body": "..."
});
```

Please help in sending these 3 cookies out to my client.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

API gateway does not let you map the same header more than once. I got around by using different casing to set-cookie method.

```
callback(null, {
    "statusCode": 302,
    "Location" : "https://somewebsite.com"
    "headers": { "Set-Cookie": cookie1, "set-Cookie": cookie2 },
    "body": "..."
});
```

Comment: It's clearly a hack of AWS API. I won't be surprised if they change that without notice.

Comment: This is a clever way to add multiple items to a Javascript object where they look different from Javascript but the same from a browser. It's not related to any AWS API.

Comment: why 2nd set cookie key have small 'set-Cookie' letter? what if i want to add 3rd cookie parameters?

Comment: I asked my self what would be the most naive way to implement such kind of thing is using a hashmap. Which make the keys should be unique. The browser does not look for casing on set-cookie. So, if you want a 3rd cookie just use a different casing.

Answer (score 24):

Use `multiValueHeaders` instead of `headers`.

```js
    const response = {
        isBase64Encoded: true,
        statusCode: 200,
        multiValueHeaders : {"Set-Cookie": [`language=${language}`, `theme=${theme}`]},
        body: JSON.stringify('User profile set successfully')
    };
    callback(null, response);
```

If you need it to be smarter, consider something like

```js
function createHeaders(headers) {
  const defaultHeaders = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  };
  const allHeaders = Object.assign({}, defaultHeaders, headers);
  const singleValueHeaders = {};
  const multiValueHeaders = {};
  Object.entries(allHeaders).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    const targetHeaders = Array.isArray(value) ? multiValueHeaders : singleValueHeaders;
    Object.assign(targetHeaders, { [key]: value });
  });

  return {
    headers: singleValueHeaders,
    multiValueHeaders,
  };
}
```

Then use it in the callback function.

```js
callback(null, {
  statusCode: status || 200,
  body: JSON.stringify(body),
  ...createHeaders({ 'Set-Cookie': cookie }),
});
```

Comment: Taken from this blog post: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/support-for-multi-value-parameters-in-amazon-api-gateway/

Answer (score 1):

I would say that your issue is related to the fact that your response object in the callback is not formatted the way the api gateway expects.

These links reference aws documentation specifically to that.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/handle-errors-in-lambda-integration.html

Issue with your code...

- 'location' does not look like a valid property
- Make sure your header key/value pairs are actual JSON objects using something like JSON.stringify

Don't forget to enable logs for both api gateway and lambda with full requests and responses. These two logs will help you debug.